# Nginx rewrite rule results in error 403

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

I am trying to rewrite a url like `http://example.com/extras/?cat=help&page=faq` to something along the lines of `http://example.com/extras/help/faq`.

Well, rewrite as in a link or a user types the latter and the server understands that it's supposed to be the former. However, after implementing the rewrite that is ostensibly supposed to do what I want, navigating to pages results in a 403 code, because the server is taking what's in the URL bar *literally*. Because I have the server set up to disallow direct access to the subfolders, the 403 code is returned.

Below is the php code on my site that handles loading the pages to be included within the `/extras` index.php:

```
if(!empty($_GET['cat']) && !empty($_GET['page'])) {
  $folder = $_GET['cat'];
  $page = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
  $pages = scandir($folder);
  unset($pages[0], $pages[1]);

  $url .= $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

  if(file_exists($url . $page) && in_array($page, $pages)) {
    $url .= $page;
    include($url);
  } else {
    //Invalid category or page given
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  }
} else {
  //No category or page given; fall back to contents
  include("contents.php");
}
```

The goal of the above file is for the contents of the subfile in the subfolders to be included in the body of index.php, not for the browser to actually try and navigate to the subfile.

This is (part of) the nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  server_name localhost;

  error_page 403 /;
  error_page 404 /error/404.php;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /error/50X.php;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @no-extension;

    allow 192.168.0.0/24;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  location /help {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @help @no-extension;
  }

  location @help {
    rewrite "^/help/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$" /help/?cat=$1&page=$2 last;
  }

  location ~ /help/(help|otherfolder|morefolders) {
    deny all;
  }

  # PHP Handler
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }

  location @no-extension {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }
}
```

Any way to make the rewrite take effect instead of the browser trying to access a file it will never be able to?

Comment: What do you think directive `try_files $uri $uri/ @help @no-extension;` should do?

Comment: I'm more used to Apache rewriting, but I can see how it might be a problem. However, I can't remove the $uri $uri/ part, or the site breaks because it refuses to load the index.php in the "help" folder.

Comment: To more directly answer the question, I don't know. It's just what "worked" for other location blocks, and I expected it would here as well. I eagerly await instruction on where I went wrong. (I'm not being sarcastic, I do mean that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while not exactly answering your question, would it not be simpler to

```
location /help {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

when you load /help/faq/ its passed in REQUEST_URI to /index.php which does the subsequent regex split and file include...no need to rewrite. specific location blocks you want to restrict should be place above, so the deny will match first (if i recall correctly)

Comment: The site works perfectly if the URL is a standard URL with PHP parameters included. What I wanted to accomplish was both changing how the URL looked in the browser bar, as well as allowing a link like http://example.com/folder/page to work, since I think the parameters in the URL are kind of ugly. Perhaps I'm missing something in your explanation?

Comment: what it does is for every url starting with /help, is execute /index.php.

so /help/file/faq, or /help/otherfile/sub, would run the index.php in / root, and that php script can find out what url you entered by the http header REQUEST_URI, which would give you the string above, "/help/file/faq", or whatever. still in php split out the / file / and / faq / and continue your script as it works currently.

the user would still see example.com/folder/page even tho its example.com/index.php that ran internally.

tried to be clearer, any better?

Comment: Yes, I think I know exactly what you're saying. I will try that out when I can, and mark this as answered then.